# Can mindi wood be used outdoors?

Tags: wood, wooden-furniture

Does anyone here have experience with mindi wood? For example furniture made from mindi wood? Is it also usable in outdoor scenarios, e.g. for garden furniture? What kind of finish is needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen window frames made out of Mindi Wood. Everything I've heard is that it's similar to teak, but not as expensive.

Answer (score 2):

I've never heard of Mindi Wood. After doing some googling, it appears that Mindi is just a term for White Cedar. If that's the case, then yes, Cedar is certainly a wood chosen for its ability to withstand the outdoor elements.

Answer (score 1):

I did use mindi wood for furniture for 5 years, but I never made outdoor furniture with mindi wood because it's softwood and not resistant to direct sunlight and water. But for indoor furniture, mindi wood's grain is very nice and more attractive then teak.